# GCP Cloud workstation DNS issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-workstations

My GCP organization has a policy to not allow using external IP addresses. I set up a private Cloud Workstation cluster, configuration and instance following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workstations/docs/configure-vpc-service-controls-private-gateway).

The problem is, that I can't connect to the created instance. When trying to launch from the browser using (using an URL like this: https://80-workstation-abcdefg.cluster-abcdefghijkl.cloudworkstations.dev), I get "DNS address could not be found".

When trying to connect with SSH, I get "ERROR: Error connecting to workstation: [Errno -2] Name or service not known".

It is a DNS error, but I can't figure out what is causing it.

I use a shared VPC, that has a CloudVPN connection to an on-prem network if it matters.

How can I connect to the created instance?

Comment: Hi, i just want to clarify, is this working before or it never worked after the configuration?

Comment: It never worked. I tried setting up a workstation in a different project with public IP and it works fine, but in this case it does not.

Comment: Based from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workstations/docs/configure-vpc-service-controls-private-gateway#enable_dns_resolution_on-premises)  have you enabled dns resolution in your on-premise network? I believed another requirement is to create a [DNS forwarding zones and DNS server policies](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/best-practices#best_practices_for_dns_forwarding_zones_and_server_policies) to allow lookups of DNS names between your on-premises and Google Cloud environment.

Comment: That's the only part I didn't complete yet, because I don't quite know how to set it up. And I don't really understand why it is needed anyway, because if I create a workstation with a public IP, the same *.cloudworkstations.dev host is assigned, but the DNS resolution is working in that case.

Comment: I believe that will be the missing part, the last step from the documentation that you follow, though I understand that in public DNS it is working, but your set up is private DNS.